# Project is tied to IDE or security?

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea

I have a Java/Spring project for which I am responsible for familiarizing myself with the code. To do this, I am debug stepping through different parts of the program and studying the variable states and call stack. I would like to run this in IDEA since I like that IDE more and have used it before. Whereas the program runs fine in Eclipse-STS, when run in IDEA, I get this:

```
[ERROR] Application [main]: Can't build application context: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [springconfig.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.Helper"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [springconfig.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.Helper"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
```

I noticed that there is a class Helper.java in our software but it is the only class in it's package so why would it complain about this class's signer information not matching that of the rest of the classes in the same package?

[image]

Elsewhere on Stack Overflow, I learned this can happen when a particular class is being imported by multiple JARs into the same project, hence causing the conflict. I wasn't sure how this conflict could be because as the image before shows this class is a native *.java file in the project and not imported from any JAR. What's more, it's the only class in it's package which makes the error message difficult to understand. But then I realized that our project also imports a JAR which has this class in it. Namely, we import `eclipselink-2.5.0.jar`. So, I thought that our source class when compiled might be conflicting with the Helper.class in this package.

So, I thought the original error message is about our Helper.class being treated as belonging to the JAR and so the IDE complaining that the JAR's manifest signature didn't match with any signature on our Helper.class.

So, as an experiment I tried to delete this JAR's signature manifest as well as delete the Helper.class from within it. Then I cleaned and recompiled the project to no avail.

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with eclipse - the IDE. You probably have conflicting eclipselink jar files. Eclipselink is your JPA persistence provider. It's a project of the Eclipse foundation, hence the package name and the project name, but which is unrelated to the Eclipse IDE.

Comment: @JBNizet What do you mean by conflicting? As in multiple jars or something? Any guidance on what to do to make it run in IDEA? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JB Nizet Still struggling with this. I'd love to know why it is that the project runs in one IDE but gives this issue in another.

Comment: I re-read your question and has a closer look at your image. It seems you're writing your own Helper class in the org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper package. Why are you doing this? Put you own class in your own package, not in eclipselink packages.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for responding again. I experimented a little and deleted the file from the code base. I was amazed to see things still appear to work. I have contacted the original author of it to see what exactly it's there for and why is the package it's in named after a package that already exists with the same name. Hopefully I can get some clues there. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.